# Passing data from view to controller and controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable

I am passing dates from the view to controller and then I will get number of Records between those two dates from controller to view. As more then one records will be fetch so I use IEnumerable so I can display list of records. But while using IEnumerable, It unable to pass selected dates from view and pass to controller. Anyone can explain me why?

This is my Code :

**View : Index.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<ApricaCRMEvent.Models.CRM.DatabaseEntities.CRM_Doctor_Request>>" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Index
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom/development-bundle/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">

<script src="../../jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom/development-bundle/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

<script src="../../jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>

<script src="../../jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>

<script src="../../jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom/development-bundle/demos/demos.css">

<script>


    function PassValue() {
        var todate = document.getElementById("Date_Modified");
        var fromdate = document.getElementById("Date_Created");
        todate.value = document.getElementById("txtToDate").value;
        fromdate.value = document.getElementById("txtFromDate").value;
    }

    $(function () {

        $("#txtToDate").datepicker({
            altField: "#alternate",
            altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy"
        });


        $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
            altField: "#alternate",
            altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy"
        });
    });

</script>

<div>
<h2>Search by Date</h2>
     <% using (Html.BeginForm())
        { %>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Profile Updation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>

         <%= Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Date_Created) %>
         <%= Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Date_Modified) %>
         <table>
            <tr>
             <td>Enter From Date</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtFromDate"></td>
            <td>Enter To Date</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtToDate"></td>

            <td><input type="submit" name="btnSearchDate" value="Search" onclick="PassValue()" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <% } %>
</div>
<div id="showtable">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Request_For_Id
        </th>
        <th>
            Territory
        </th>
        <th>
            Estimated_Amount
        </th>
        <th>
            Actual_Amount
        </th>
        <th>
            Date_Created
        </th>
        <th>
            Compute_CRM_State
        </th>
        <th>
            Compute_Event_Type
        </th>
    </tr>
    <% foreach (var item in Model)
       { %>
     <tr>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Request_For_Id)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Territory)%>
        </td>

        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Estimated_Amount)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Actual_Amount)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date_Created)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Compute_CRM_State)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Compute_Event_Type)%>
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <%} %>
</table>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ApricaCRMEvent.Models.CRM.DatabaseEntities;
using ApricaCRMEvent.Models.CRM.DataLayer;

namespace ApricaCRMEvent.Controllers.CRM
{
    public class SearchDateWiseController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /SearchDateWise/
        CRM_Doctor_Request dateObj = new CRM_Doctor_Request();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(CRM_Doctor_Request model)
        {

    return View(SearchMDLNoDL.getDateWiseDetails(model.Date_Created,model.Date_Modified).ToList());
        }

    }
}
```

While using IEnumerable showing compilation error

```
Line 49:         <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Profile Updation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>
Line 50: 
Line 51:          **<%= Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Date_Created) %>
Line 52:          <%= Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Date_Modified) %>**
Line 53:          <table>
```

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Date_Created' and no extension method 'Date_Created' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you posting Enumerable data to controller ?

Comment: @Karthik  No, only I am just passing two dates only.

Comment: Problem is when you are getting values from controller to view ?

Comment: @Karthik No, While sending Dates from View to controller. See, I have added my Compilation error too after the code.

Comment: @Karthik  I a getting error on Line no. 51.

Comment: @Karthik  And when I Remove IEnumerable from the page then data can pass from controller to view.. But later on I will not get list of data that will return from View to Controller as I remove IEnumberable.

Comment: Are you using `@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>` in your view ?

Comment: @Karthik No, here it is <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<ApricaCRMEvent.Models.CRM.DatabaseEntities.CRM_Doctor_Request>>" %>

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
  <% foreach (var date in Model) { %>
        <%= Html.HiddenFor(date=>date.Date_Created) %>
        <%= Html.HiddenFor(date=>date.Date_Modified) %>
    <% } %>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Your view model in this case is an IEnumurable. It only contains methods defined on enumerators. You have two options.

Option one: Define a view model such as the following

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public CRM_Doctor_Request ReportRequests { get; set;}
    public DateTime Date_Created { get; set;}
    public DateTime Date_Modified { get; set;}
}
```

You can now use this view model to pass data to the view.

Second option: Use ViewBag to pass the dates to the view. In your controller

```
ViewBag.Date_Created = dateCreated;
ViewBag.Date_Modified = dateModified;
```

Now these values can now be accessed from the View

Personally I would go for option one due to its cleanness

Comment: He is enumerating the collection though, this doesn't apply